# How to recurse through folders and determine the folder size?

Tags: windows, powershell, directory, powershell-2.0

I have a slightly modified version of a script presented in "[Windows PowerShell Tip of the Week](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730945.aspx)". The idea is to determine the size of a folder and its subfolders:

```
$startFolder = "C:\Temp\"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty count)
"$startFolder -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object)
foreach ($i in $colItems)
    {
        $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
        $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
    }
```

This script runs fine but with certain folders I get an error saying:

```
Measure-Object : Property "length" cannot be found in any object(s) input.
At line:10 char:70
+         $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object <<<<  -property length -sum)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Measure-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GenericMeasurePropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureObjectCommand
```

What is the reason for this error and how to refine the script to overcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-ErrorAction` parameter for `Measure-Object`:

```
$subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
```

or its alias `-ea` with a numeric value, which is nice for quickly adding it in interactive experimentation:

```
$subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum -ea 0)
```

In my humble opinion the script on Technet is very poor PowerShell code, though.

As a very quick and dirty (and slow) solution you can also use the following one-liner:

```
# Find folders
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
# Find cumulative size of the directories and put it into nice objects
ForEach-Object {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Path = $_.FullName
        Size = [Math]::Round((Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.FullName | Measure-Object Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1MB, 2)
    }
} |
# Exclude empty directories
Where-Object { $_.Size -gt 0 } |
# Format nicely
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Or actually as a one-liner:

```
gci -r|?{$_.PSIsContainer}|%{New-Object PSObject -p @{Path=$_.FullName;Size=[Math]::Round((gci -r $_.FullName|measure Length -s -ea 0).Sum/1MB,2)}}|?{$_.Size}|ft -a
```

Comment: Thanks, your solutions is far more better!

Comment: You can make it better by caching deeper directories and re-use their size when computing those further up the hierarchy. I.e. memoization to avoid re-computing the deeper directory sizes over and over again.

Answer (score -1):

I'm running it on Windows 7, and it works (cutting and pasting your code). Maybe there is a file with a "not good name" in your path?

Comment: It happens if there are only directories in a particular directory since `DirectoryInfo` has no `Length` property.

Comment: +1 @Joey - yes, I am getting the same error from Measure-Object, and yours is the only explanation that explains it.  Thanks.